# Adding the integer values inside JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

For example I have this JSON.

```
[{"rate":3},{"rate":4},{"rate":3},{"rate":5}]
```

What can I do so I can add all the values inside of it in PHP. Thaanks :)

So this is the code goes srry.

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

$query = "SELECT rate FROM tbl_ratings WHERE userID = 10";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$json = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $json[]=$row;
}
}
mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($json, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo array_sum($json, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

Comment: Use the `array_sum()` function?

Comment: Can it be possible that you add this all json elements and then send it to php? will it work?

Comment: Decode the JSON, process the resulting object, encode it back if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reconfigure your json string to suit the method -- just add `array_column()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9APjO))

```
// these are subarrays containing 1 element each
$json = '[{"rate":3},{"rate":4},{"rate":3},{"rate":5}]';

// decode it to an array    
$array = json_decode($json, true);

// extract the "rate" column values from each subarray and sum them
echo array_sum(array_column($array, 'rate'));
```

Output:

```
15
```

---

...but honestly, it looks like you have over-complicated the task.  Just add it all up using MySQL.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(rate) FROM tbl_ratings WHERE userID = 10");
echo mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];  //15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Your json decode
$json = json_decode($YourJson);
//summation of all elements
$total = array_sum($jaon);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `JSON` in incorrect. It should have proper square brackets. Before 3, there should be opening square bracket and not `{`
2. You should do `json_decode()`
3. Use `array_sum()` to get the sum of all values.

Below is the code:

```
$json = '{"rates": [3,2,3,5,7]}';
$arr = json_decode($json);
echo array_sum($arr->rates);
```